# xgb.plot.multi.trees What is the meaning of the numbers in the parentheses?

Tags: r, decision-tree, xgboost

It isn't number of trees, since I only trained 25. It also isn't the value of the variable. This is evident by the scale of the values in the parenthesis, which doesn't make sense since many variables are logged. I checked the documentation and there was no explanation. Any ideas or other references?

```
df1 <- xgb.train(data = X_train_dmat, 
               eta = 0.1,
               max_depth = 5, 
               nround=25, 
               subsample = 0.5,
               colsample_bytree = 0.5,
               booster = 'gbtree',
               objective = 'reg:squarederror',
               nthread = 3
)

xgb.plot.multi.trees(model = df1, 
                     features_keep = 5, 
                     use.names=FALSE,
                     plot_width = NULL,
                     plot_height = NULL,
                     render = TRUE
                     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/R/xgb.plot.multi.trees.R#L94, this is the part creating the nodes in the tree:

```
  nodes.dt <- tree.matrix[
        , .(Quality = sum(Quality))
        , by = .(abs.node.position, Feature)
      ][, .(Text = paste0(Feature[1:min(length(Feature), features_keep)],
                          " (",
                          format(Quality[1:min(length(Quality), features_keep)], digits=5),
                          ")") %>%
                   paste0(collapse = "\n"))
        , by = abs.node.position]
```

Specifically, this is the code that writes those numbers:

```
format(Quality[1:min(length(Quality), features_keep)], digits=5)
```

So, those numbers show the quality of each node, which *I think* reflects how appropriately that node divides the data. It's been a while since I dealt with these models and I've never been savvy, so I cannot be sure of my interpretation. If you want further explanation about the meaning of quality, you may dig deeper in the source code to figure out how it gets calculated.

Comment: thanks for looking at the source code. that probably isn't write either since it looks the source code is rounding/truncating to 5 digits whereas in my figure there are values with more digits than that.

Comment: @user2205916 wrong. It is not truncating. It is formatting. It affects number of decimals, if a number is greater than 1e5 then it just removes the decimals. It is certainly the code that creates those tags in your question.

Comment: @user2205916 to further understand `format` function, you can run this code: ```options(scipen = 999); format(100000, digits = 5); format(100000.23, digits = 5); format(1.23562326, digits = 5)```. `options` just turns off the scientific notation so it's in the same format as what you see from the package.